# How to fix Ntdll.dll APPCRASH with Hardware ID Extractor?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using the Hardware ID Extractor library (written in Delphi) from https://soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/ with the purpose of generating unique system fingerprints.

The library is really good and unlike anything else I have seen on the market, but the main issue with it is that it's unstable when running with .NET applications, meaning that it sometimes works, other times it works for a few function calls then the main application crashes, or most of the time the application instantly crashes when a dll function is being called.

As the developer of the library pointed out (in the last support e-mail that I have received), the fault is with ntdll.dll, as I have seen that for myself:
[image]

Following is a link to a demo project I have created with the purpose of testing the dll functions (so to make sure that nothing else interferes, the demo app does that and only that- it calls the dll functions).
http://www.mediafire.com/download/1jws7zh9218v88a/HardwareIdExtractDllTest.zip
The archive contains the Visual Studio 2013 project with source code and a compiled demo application which looks like this:
[image]

The list of functions contained by the dll can be found here:
https://soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/hardware%20id%20programming%20source%20code/exported%20functions%20for%20non-Delphi.html

If anyone has the knowledge and is willing to test the demo project/application to make tests or personal opinions in regard to the issue, and then share a possible solution with me, I would be grateful.

Please let me know if there's anything I can do to further assist in solving this issue if you think there's anything that can be done about it.

**EDIT: This is how I am declaring the dll functions**

```
    [DllImport("HardwareIDExtractorC.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnterKey(int key);

    [DllImport("HardwareIDExtractorC.dll")]
    private static extern bool IsCPUIDAvailable();

    [DllImport("HardwareIDExtractorC.dll")]
    private static extern int GetCPUCount();

    [DllImport("HardwareIDExtractorC.dll")]
    private static extern byte CoreNumber2CoreMask(byte cpuCore);

    [DllImport("HardwareIDExtractorC.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "GetCPUID")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    private static extern string GetCPUID(byte cpuCore);

    [DllImport("HardwareIDExtractorC.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "GetCpuIdNow")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    private static extern string GetCpuIdNow(); 

    [DllImport("HardwareIDExtractorC.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "GetIDESerialNumber")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    private static extern string GetIDESerialNumber(byte driveNumber);
```

Comment: No, the fault is not in ntdll. The developer of the library is shirking responsibility. If you call certain win32 library functions passing incorrect input then you may encounter faults in those win32 libraries. But the fault is in your code. Or in this case the developer off the unmanaged code.

Comment: Ok, but how can we know for certain who's the real culprit if the crash is random (i.e. can't be reliably reproduced, even if the crash happens more often)? Their free software works without any issues (granted, the software is standalone and the functionality is embedded) and since the dll does work at times, I'd point the finger at ntdll.

Comment: I assure you this is not an Windows bug

Comment: Alright, but if the fault is in my code and/or the unmanaged library, wouldn't that mean that the application should crash every time?

Comment: Also, it would only take a few hours to write robust code that would get all those ids

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about it.. the ID's their library generates are truly unique and unlike any other (free/commercial) solution I have ever encountered by now, that's why I bought the dll from them.

Comment: If you don't believe me, submit a bug report to ms

Comment: No, it doesn't mean the app would crash every time. It would only crash when the application or DLL takes a code path that causes a memory corruption or generates an invalid value that then makes its way into a call to NTDLL.DLL and causes the crash. As @David says, the chances of this being a Windows bug are negligible, with the chances of the issue being in your (or the library's) code being about 99.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999%.

Comment: I understand and I can not argue further since you are experienced users and I barely have any solid knowledge regarding the issue. Thank you for your time. I will try to communicate more about this with the developers in an attempt to find a solution.

Comment: It's plausible also that your C# wrapper is at fault. It's very hard for us to say anything more specific because we can't see the code.

Comment: The linked archive contains everything needed for full tests.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/1jws7zh9218v88a/HardwareIdExtractDllTest.zip

Comment: Why would we want to download that? It its not in the question it doesn't count.

Comment: Um... yeah, it is in the original question, it has always been.. I just pasted it in the comment for your clicking convenience.

Comment: No. Code should be in the question. Nobody wants to go to off site links.

Comment: I have added code samples to the original post, please let me know what else I should add if needed for the solution.

Comment: From what you've shown are failing only functions that return string (saying that to narrow the problem).

Comment: Yes, it's the ones that return PAnsiChar in the source dll, but they fail unpredictably, meaning sometimes they do, sometimes they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions that fail are the ones that return `string`. Such a p/invoke marshals the return value as a pointer to null terminated character array, and then calls `CoTaskMemFree` on the raw pointer returned by the unmanaged code.

With probability close to 1 that string was not allocated on the COM heap and so the error is likely in the C# p/invoke declarations. That an access violation then arises in ntdll is quite plausible.

So, to make progress you need to fix the p/invoke calls. I cannot tell you how to do so because you have not shown the unmanaged function declarations. Or, more importantly, how the memory is allocated.

---

There are some clues at the [documentation](https://soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/hardware%20id%20programming%20source%20code/exported%20functions%20for%20non-Delphi.html)

```
procedure ReleaseMemory (P: PAnsiChar); stdcall;
```

I think this tells us that the strings returned by the DLL must be deallocated by the DLL, by calling this function. Presumably because they were allocated by the DLL's heap allocator.

So, use `IntPtr` for the return type of the functions that return text. Call `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` to convert to a C# string. And then pass the pointer to `ReleaseMemory`.

For example:

```
[DllImport(DllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern IntPtr GetCPUID(ushort CoreMask);

[DllImport(DllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern void ReleaseMemory(IntPtr P);

....

IntPtr ptr = GetCPUID(CoreMask);
string cpuid = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
ReleaseMemory(ptr);
```

Comment: Could you please provide an explicit C# code example on how to call a function so I can test it in my project, and mark the answer as valid if it works?

Comment: You truly are a master and I apologize if I seemed to be stubborn and arrogant, I just spent so much time trying to figure out how to make this work, I was acting stupid after I have learned that it works by using AnsiBStr.

This works flawlessly! Thank you very much!

Comment: This has been quite painful. In my view what's important for you is not learning how to call this DLL. What is important is learning how to solve a problem. Guesswork and trial and error are not robust techniques. It's not uncommon to try something that appears to work but is in fact incorrect. That's what has happened here. A common example is when people write off the end of an array and then read back the answer. It seems to work. Doesn't mean that the code is correct. Undefined behaviour can be confusing.

Comment: I recognise the desire to declare a problem solved and move on, but sometimes one wishes to do that more out of hope than belief. I really hope that you can learn from this. I hope you don't take that the wrong way, and it may sound patronising. But with respect, I remember "solving" problems like this in my early days and it never ended well. I applaud you for sticking with me!

Comment: I really wish this was documented by the developer of the dll instead of having to go through all this, but I am certainly not calling it a waste of time, it has been an opportunity for me to learn more.

The answer/solution you provided seems to be of extreme finesse and I hardly imagine figuring out the proper solution on my own. My gratitude for being willing to show me the right path despite past misunderstandings.

Comment: The developer of this DLL has done a poor job of documenting it, that's for sure!